# Python scapy nmap_fp "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'res'"

Tags: python, scapy

I have a very simple python script, trying to test `nmap_fp` module from `scapy`

```
from scapy.all import *
ip = 'just.an.ip.range'
print(nmap_fp(ip))
```

Now when I run I get the following Error:

```
Begin emission:
...Finished to send 8 packets.
*......
Received 10 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 7 packets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scapy_.py", line 7, in <module>
    ans = nmap_fp(my_phone_ip_2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/modules/nmap.py", line 189, in nmap_fp
    sigs = nmap_sig(target, oport, cport)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/modules/nmap.py", line 144, in nmap_sig
    ans += map(lambda x: (x,None), unans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/plist.py", line 89, in _add_
    return self.__class__(self.res+other.res,
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'res'
```

**edit**

Using `scapy Version: 2.3.3`

Comment: Which version of Scapy are you using?

Comment: scapy Version: 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably upgrade to the current [development version](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), since some Nmap-related issues have been fixed since the last release. You will also need to use the previous version of Nmap fingerprints.